# time calculation gets "date cannot be cast"

Tags: java, android, time

i have an error in my time calculations

as i do not have a lot of experience with time calculations it would be nice to have some help

my code that runs an error

```
Calendar c = Calendar .getInstance();

    //uur ophalen
    SimpleDateFormat uf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String stoptijd =uf.format(c.getTime());

    //datum ophalen
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    String datum = df.format(c.getTime());

    //werknemernummer ophalen
    // TODO
    int werknemer = 5;

    //uitrekenen hoeveel totaaluren moet zijn
    String Starttijd = bezur.leesbegintijd(bezoeknummer);
    SimpleDateFormat datumberekening = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    long werktijd = 0;

        try {
            Date stopt = (Date) datumberekening.parse(stoptijd);
            Date startt;

            startt = (Date) datumberekening.parse(Starttijd);
            werktijd = stopt.getTime() - startt.getTime();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

my logcat:

```
10-28 19:54:11.914: E/AndroidRuntime(23145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 19:54:11.914: E/AndroidRuntime(23145): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
10-28 19:54:11.914: E/AndroidRuntime(23145):    at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten.stopwerkuren(bezoekrapporten.java:200)
10-28 19:54:11.914: E/AndroidRuntime(23145):    at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten.handlescan(bezoekrapporten.java:117)
10-28 19:54:11.914: E/AndroidRuntime(23145):    at com.example.deceunincktechniekers.bezoekrapporten$1.onEditorAction(bezoekrapporten.java:51)
```

what can be done better??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing the wrong class, `java.sql.Date` is different from `java.util.Date`. The `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` returns a `java.util.Date`. `java.sql.Date` is only useful if you're working with SQL - if so you can convert a `java.util.Date` to it as follows:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(datumberekening.parse(stoptijd).getTime());
```